# Segmentation fault: 11 on c program

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, segmentation-fault, scanf

In my code:

```
int nAlunos, nNotas;

/*size input*/

scanf("%d", &nAlunos);

scanf("%d", &nNotas);

/*arrays*/

int ordenador [nAlunos];
char listaNomes [nAlunos][16];
float listaNotas [nAlunos][nNotas+1];

/*non-arrays*/

int i, k;

/*input*/

for(i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++){
    scanf("%s", listaNomes[i]);
    for(k = 1; k <= nNotas; k++){
        scanf("%f", &listaNotas[i][k]);
    }
}


/*sum of grades / number os grades for each person*/

for(i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++){
    listaNotas[i][0] = 0;

    for(k = 1; k <= nNotas; k++)
        listaNotas[i][0] += listaNotas[i][k];

    listaNotas[i][0] /= nNotas;
}


/*process order on vector*/

for(i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++){
    menor = 1111;

    for(k = i; k < nAlunos; k++)
        if (listaNotas[k][0] < menor)
            menor = listaNotas[k][0];

    for(k = i; listaNotas[k][0] != menor; k++){}

    ordenador[k] = i;
    ordenador[i] = k;
}
for(i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++)
    printf("%d", ordenador[i]);
```

}

I am trying to fill a table of data from the user, I may not use pointers for this class.

it needs to receive data as presented:

```
String1
float1 float2...
String2
.
.
.
```

When running it, it works well until I finish with the last input. After that it just breaks the execution and returns me segmentation fault: 11

I tried to find where could it be accessing improper memory, but it just doesn't make sense to me because I cannot find it.

Comment: I cannot use dynamic allocation, and I need the listaNotas[i][0] for other means, so I won't write on it yet.

Comment: So your program breaks some time _after_ what you've posted above? Why don't you show the rest thenn? (@Joni: VLAs are perfectly cromulent C.)

Comment: This code is running fine on GCC.

Comment: Why is it `scanf("%s", listaNomes[i])` and not `scanf("%s", listaNomes[i*16])`? (looking at your definition for the array `listaNomes`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  In a context like this, it is a good idea to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)); it is easier to see what is going wrong.  It would also help to have information about the data you are entering.  You are not checking the return values from `scanf()` to ensure that the conversions are working (but you should).  You are not limiting the amount of input (you should use `"%15s"` for reading the string to ensure no buffer overflow.  However, given valid data, it should be OK so far.

Comment: @Joni: Standard C99 and C11 (if enabled) allow you to use VLAs — variable length arrays.

Comment: @Joni, it's fine to declare them like that
after reading input i use the [i][0] space to place the medium between the inputs

Comment: @JacobPollack: The `scanf("%s", listaNomes[i])` is fine (with caveats about unrestrained length — it should be `"%15s"` to ensure no buffer overflow).

Comment: @UchiaItachi it runs fine, but it gets stuck after the last input, i tried printing something and it wont go pass what i posted here

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, but `i` would range from 0 ... `nAlunos` and since he declared a multi-dimensional array he needs to be populating `i*cols + cols` in the outer for loop, otherwise he may write a string "Hello" and then write "Hi" and the array becomes "HHilo".

Comment: Please show us the inputs which you're entering and the values which you're trying to print. Paste that part of your code also.

Comment: @JacobPollack: nonsense!  `listaNomes[i]` is the `i`th sub-array of 16 characters.  If it was a 1D array, you'd be correct, but `char listaNomes[nAlunos][16];` is a 2D array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, i will. i tried putting the %15s and it returns the same thing

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ah I suppose I did not realize that `[i]` alone will be the `i`th sub-array for a 2D array. I assumed that even though it was a 2D array it would imply `*( arr + k )` (as a 1D array would).

Comment: @JoãoMiranda : Why don't you post what you tried and the whole code?

Comment: well, i guessed it wont matter what i coded after that, i mean, i added a `printf("test");` right after and it doesn't print it at all.

Comment: @Skippy, thanks for the feedback, sorry for my english, i'm not american but i try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(k = i; listaNotas[k][0] != menor; k++){}
```

The above statement is causing the out of bound access of the array! Hence the `segmentation fault`. Handle it according to your functionality.

The condition `listaNotas[k][0] != menor` is fatal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple adaptation of your code, with error checking on the `scanf()` calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void err_exit(const char *msg);

int main(void)
{
    int nAlunos, nNotas;

    if (scanf("%d", &nAlunos) != 1 || scanf("%d", &nNotas) != 1)
        err_exit("failed to read dimensions");

    char listaNomes[nAlunos][16];
    float listaNotas[nAlunos][nNotas+1];
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%s", listaNomes[i]) != 1)
            err_exit("failed to read name");

        for (k = 1; k <= nNotas; k++)
        {
            if (scanf("%f", &listaNotas[i][k]) != 1)
                err_exit("failed to read grade");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nAlunos; i++)
    {
        printf("%s:", listaNomes[i]);
        for (k = 1; k <= nNotas; k++)
            printf(" %f", listaNotas[i][k]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

static void err_exit(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

Given the input file:

```
3
4
name-the-first
12 13 14 15
name-the-second
21 22 23 24
name-the-third
31 310 3109 31098
```

The output from the program is:

```
name-the-first: 12.000000 13.000000 14.000000 15.000000
name-the-second: 21.000000 22.000000 23.000000 24.000000
name-the-third: 31.000000 310.000000 3109.000000 31098.000000
```

This is what should be expected.

The only oddity in the code is the use of `for (k = 1; k <= nNotas; k++)` because it leaves `listaNotas[i][0]` uninitialized and unused.  You did, however, allocate enough space so that isn't a cause of trouble.

#### Summary

The problem is not self-evidently in the code you showed.  Please show the actual code that crashes!

Comment: I updated the post with the whole code, it's not finished, I was testing it so far